# NullPointerExcetption with AppCompat and ActionBar

Tags: java, android

The Activity I have crashes everytime with this error. If I add any code related to `getSupportActionBar()` it crashes within that. Otherwise it crashes out of that

```
public class DishTag extends ActionBarActivity  implements OnClickListener{
 //....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setContentView(R.layout.dish_tag);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       context=this;
       //literally all the code I have
       ActionBar a=getSupportActionBar();
       a.setTitle("SD"); 
    }
}
```

To be noted and I don't know if this makes any difference but I am using a `ViewPager` on the page.

The error is

```
11-30 22:06:38.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27315): Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt  to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a
null object reference
```

Comment: For what? I don't get what I'm missing here. I have `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel Checked imports several times. No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer.

I tried setting the content view before runnning the `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.dish_tag);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```